# Is there any way to migrate from Microsoft knowledge base to Plone knowledge base CMS?

Tags: plone, knowledge-management

I was working on IIS and Microsoft's Knowledge base CMS but I want to switch to open source and Linux based CMS which can handle easily knowledge base management stuffs.

I know Plone could be best solution. But

> how to migrate all the data from Microsoft Knowledge Base to Plone?

**Any idea?**

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Knowledge_Base - Migrate from *there*?

Comment: No, we can use Microsoft knowledge base platform to build our own knowledge base system for our sites. <br /> I have my own MS kbase based knowledge repositories for my site which I need to move to Plone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look for transmogrify based packages as your starter, say, transmogrify.webcrawler or funnelweb. Or, write migration scripts reading from Microsoft database and import the data into Plone. Hope this helpful.

Comment: That was quite useful. Plone could be better choice but I didn't had to indtroduce new technologies this time, so I went with wordpress module for Q&A, so that I can use MySQL skills :)